# Objective C Interface Builder ARC - retain custom Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

In an iPhone App I've got a view with a button on it. The Button is connected to an `IBAction` of MyClass.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject   
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

As soon as I click this button, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The class `MyClass` was added to the view by using the "Object" component from the right sidebar.

I think this is because my custom controller gets deallocated by ARC. Is this correct? Are objects which are added via the interface controller not automatically retained? How to retain the instance which I have connected via interface builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `MyClass` must be a subclass of `UIView`, not `NSObject`.
2. If you think an object is being deallocated prematurely, implement the `-dealloc` method and add some logging and a breakpoint.
3. If your custom view is on screen then its superview will hold a reference to that view and it will not be deallocated.  If your custom view controller has a parent view controller such as a UINavigationController then its parent view controller will hold a reference to your view controller and it will not be deallocated.
4. Set a breakpoint in your `-buttonPressed:` method to confirm that it's being called correctly.  Then step through the code.
5. Look at the call stack at the time of the EXC_BAD_ACCESS to better isolate where the problem is.  Is your -buttonPressed: method actually being called?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first thing first. Why are you adding the IBAction to your class? Since it's the controller that should have the outlet to handle the event. What is this class?

You must instantiate it in your controller (don't know exactly how you hooked this up) and retain it in order for it to take effect, since it's probably becoming nil since nothing is holding it.

This is simply bad practice, the logic for your actions should be handled by the controller itself, that's the function of a controller, so it would be better to hook the action up in the controller.

Comment: The class `MyClass` should act as a "custom controller" - an additional one to the view controller already present. In the future `MyClass` will retrieve data when IBAction is performed, and will present this data in a table via an IBOutlet.

Comment: Should, but you're not extending a controller, so it's not doing any view handling, and I still don't get how you hooked everything up, did you use interface builder? And what is the poing of having a "custom controller" inside you controller? You do not need this class in order to achieve what you need.

Comment: I created an obj-c class `MyClass`, added the IBAction, added a "Object" component (the thing with the yellow sphere as icon), and changed the class in the identity inspector to `MyClass`. All right? The reason for doing this is to separate DB related IBActions from all other ones.

Comment: You are seriously going against the MVC architecture that is supposed to be used. You have no real model, which is the one that should do the DB calls, not the controller itself. You say you added the IBAction but did you hook it up to the button? Either in IB or in code? Added a "Object" component to what?

Comment: If you still wanna go down this path, you must create a property in your view controller to hold your MyClass object, all you're really doing is adding another unnecessary layer to your application.